# Can't create database from storage server

Tags: wso2

**RSS Instanec configuration:**

[image: RSS Instance]
When insert name of existing database it successfully added, but when I try to create a database get output :

> Failed to create database 'testDatabase' : RSSAdminRSSManagerExceptionExceptionError while creating the database 'testDatabase' on RSS instance 'pop' : Error while acquiring datasource connection : FATAL: database "testDatabase" does not exist

Comment: So what happens is you can create a database server instance successfully, but you can't create databases. Is my understanding correct? Is it the same if you configure database server via config file? https://docs.wso2.com/display/SS150/Configuring+RSS+Environments